# Event when Firebase Function instance is about to get stopped

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

With the upcoming [Cloud Function v2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta?hl=en#new-in-2) allowing requests concurrency i m wondering if there is a way to execute code within it when this instance is about to get stopped?

I d like to batch up non-critical data accumulated in the cloud-function instance RAM and dump it to  a firestore document only once the instance is about to stop so it may save some firestore writes.

Something like:

```js
let count =0;

export function counting(req:https.Request, res:Response){
    count++;
    res.status(200);
}

export function FIREBASE_INSTANCE_DROP_EVENT(e){
    saveToFirestore(count);
}
```

Comment: Ongoing work on indeterminate duration isn't really a good use case for Cloud Functions.  I don't think you'll find an event that works, and I suspect you are only going to have problems making this work in a way that's not supported.  If you have some need for persistent memory, consider using memcached instead, or a different compute product entirely that doesn't force instances to shut down on an indeterminate schedule.

Comment: I ll just dump data to firestore every few calls then... That's still the cheapest solution in my situation.